# SSL - create private.key from private-key.pem for Apache

Tags: ssl, openssl

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.freshblurbs.com/blog/2013/09/21/geotrust-rapidssl-amazon-aws-elb.html) to generate a `private-key.pem` and `csr.pem` for my AWS SSL Loadbalancer.
Everything went well but now I need to setup Apache and need 3 files.

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/public.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/private.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/intermediate.crt
```

From my files `private-key.pem`, `csr.pem`, `cert.pem` and `ca.pem` 
how can i generate `public.crt`,  `private.key` and `intermediate.crt`?

here is my `.conf` entry

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        ServerName www.mydomain.com
        ServerAlias mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/conf.log
        <Directory /var/www/mydomain.com>
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    ServerAdmin contact@mydomain.com               
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.com
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/conf.log
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/private-key.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca.pem
    #ServerPath /home
    <Directory "/var/www/mydomain.com">
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin 
SSLSessionCache shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000) 
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300 
Mutex default 
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 256 
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin 
SSLCryptoDevice builtin
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be fooled by a files extension - they have very little meaning on a Unix system.

`SSLCertificateKeyFile` should point to a PEM formatted key file which your private-key.pem should all ready be. So you can just point to it in your Apache config.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatekeyfile

Comment: thanks!  how about the 2 `crt` files?

Comment: Those are the files you received from your certificate provider.

Comment: I still cant connect with `https`, would you recommend i save those `pem` files as `crt` and `key` extensions?

Comment: That would be a waste of time as Apache doesn't care about the extension. What does it say in your log files?

Comment: `/var/log/conf.log` is empty,  i made sure the ownership is set to apache

Comment: What about Apache's own error log, usually /var/log/apache2/error.log or /var/log/httpd/error.log?

Comment: im getting `[ssl:warn] [pid 15444] AH01916: Init: (mydomain.com:443) You configured HTTP(80) on the standard HTTPS(443) port!`

Comment: Well then your problem isn't about certificates :-) I haven't seen that particular error before, but try Google or asking a new question.